# Is it possible to combine parameters to a subset function that is generated programmatically in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Before my question, here is a little background.

I am creating a general purpose data shaping and charting library for plotting survey data of a particular format.

As part of my scripts, I am using the subset function on my data frame. The way I am working is that I have a parameter file where I can pass this subsetting criteria into my functions (so I don't need to directly edit my main library). The way I do this is as follows:

```
subset_criteria <- expression(variable1 != "" & variable2 == TRUE)
```

(where variable1 and variable2 are columns in my data frame, for example).

Then in my function, I call this as follows:

```
my.subset <- subset(my.data, eval(subset_criteria))
```

This part works exactly as I want it to work. But now I want to augment that subsetting criteria inside the function, based on some other calculations that can only be performed inside the function. So I am trying to find a way to combine together these subsetting expressions.

Imagine inside my function I create some new column in my data frame automatically, and then I want to add a condition to my subsetting that says that this additional column must be TRUE.

Essentially, I do the following:

```
my.data$newcolumn <- with(my.data, ifelse(...some condition..., TRUE, FALSE))
```

Then I want my subsetting to end up being:

```
my.subset <- subset(my.data, eval(subset_criteria & newcolumn == TRUE))
```

But it does not seem like simply doing what I list above is valid. I get the wrong solution. So I'm looking for a way of combining these expressions using expression and eval so that I essentially get the combination of all the conditions.

Thanks for any pointers. It would be great if I can do this without having to rewrite how I do all my expressions, but I understand that might be what is needed...

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably avoid two things: using `subset` in non-interactive setting (see warning in the help pages) and `eval(parse())`. Here we go.

You can change the expression into a string and append it whatever you want. The trick is to convert the string back to expression. This is where the aforementioned `parse` comes in.

```
sub1 <- expression(Species == "setosa")

subset(iris, eval(sub1))

sub2 <- paste(sub1, '&', 'Petal.Width > 0.2')

subset(iris, eval(parse(text = sub2)))  # your case

> subset(iris, eval(parse(text = sub2)))
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
27          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
41          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
```